# Sharing the Eclipse window in Zoom

Tags: eclipse, video-conferencing

Is there a way to share the Eclipse window when using the Zoom videoconference app? I can share about any window (even Chromium), but the Eclipse window doesn't appear in the share options. I know I can share the desktop, but I'd rather share a window. Is there an option to change in Eclipse to make this possible (like hardware acceleration, but I didn't find one)?

Using Eclipse 2020-06 on Kubuntu 19.10 with NVidia driver 435.21